# Задача транспонировать таблицу в clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что в заголовках даты каждого дня месяца. Отчет мне будут присылать каждый месяц, количество колонок будет меняться, и заголовки тоже. А мне нужно настроить ETL-процесс, универсальный для всех случаев.
Всю голову уже сломала. Подскажите, как привести этот кошмар к виду:

1  3.4 01.10.2022

1  3.4 02.10.2022

1  4.4 03.10.2022

1  4.4 04.10.2022

10 4.4 01.10.2022

Comment: Как из **этого** должно получиться, допустим **1 3.4 01.10.2022**?

Comment: а что это за тул и что там за select в верхней строчке? как вообще данные в таблице выглядят (не может же в ней быть по столбцу на каждую дату, это уже результат трансформации)

Comment: Обычный UNION. `SELECT id, value_01102022, '01/10/2022' FROM table UNION ALL SELECT id, value_02102022, '02/10/2022' FROM table UNION ALL ..`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+pivot